# Using reflection to inspect collections inside a class

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I have code looking like this:

```dart
Zoo myZoo;

class Zoo {
  Park<Duck> ducks;
  Park<Lama> lamas;
}

class Park<E extends Animal> {
  ...
}
```

I need to know from a ClassMirror of Zoo how many Park there are and what kind of subtype of Animal they contains. Actually I'd need to retrieve the Duck and Lama TypeMirrors in this example.

So far I've been able to print that out by parsing strings, but I can't manage to actually retrieve the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear to me but I guess this is what you are looking for

```dart
void main() {
  ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(Zoo);
  cm.declarations.forEach((k, v) {
    if(v is VariableMirror) {
      if ((v as VariableMirror).type.typeArguments.where((t) => t.isSubtypeOf(reflectType(Animal))).length > 0) {
        print('$k, $v');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome you saved my day! I didn't knew about ClassMirror typeArguments, that was what I was looking for. Thanks :)